# I wrote a mortgage calculator code but when i debugged it i got an exception

Tags: java, number-formatting, numberformatexception

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

 public class Mortgage {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p = 1000000;
   NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
   double r = Double.parseDouble(percent.format(3.92*12));

    int t = (int)(r);
    double n;
    n = Math.pow(30,12);
    int f = (int) Math.floor(n);

    int a =(1+t)^f;
    int b = (a-1);
    int c = (t*a)/b;
    int m = p*c;
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String result = currency.format(m);

    System.out.println(result);

    }
 }
```

I have tried to changed `r` to `int` but I still got exception. What am I not writing correctly?

Comment: What is the exception you got? Can you include that in your question?

Comment: What exception ? What error ? don't force us to run the code to see it ;)

Comment: What did you expect at the end ? change the name of your variable, it's not understandable

Comment: Always, always, always include the full text of the error message if you're running into an error you can't rectify. You're asking strangers to help you for free -- don't make things harder than they need to be. In case anyone was wondering: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,704%"`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,704%"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at com.example.tunji.Mortgage.main(Mortgage.java:9)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,704%"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at com.example.tunji.Mortgage.main(Mortgage.java:9)

Comment: @Amaka_k if you want to add additional information to your question always edit the question instead of burying the information in the comments. This is because the comments may become hidden, if there are too much of them.

Comment: okay thank you, its my second time.

Comment: `int a =(1+t)^f;` does not do what you think it does. `^` is the binary XOR operator in Java, not exponentiation. To do exponentiation you need `double a = Math.pow(1 + t, f);` Also - what do you think `Math.pow(30,12)` does? 30 to the twelfth power is a humongous number, and you won't be able to hold that in an `int`; your call to `Math.floor(n)` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You use `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` to format your number. This adds a `%` symbol and other number formatting (depending on your default locale). Then the `Double.parseDouble(...)` call fails because the number is not a pure double number.

There is no need to format and parse the number, you can just assign it directly to the double variable as it is a constant anyways.

Comment: It's not just the % symbol... number format is adding a comma to group digits.

Comment: okay let me do that now

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems.

```java
    double n;
    n = Math.pow(30,12);
    int f = (int) Math.floor(n);
```

30 to the 12th power.  That does not make sense for a 30 year mortgage  Did you mean `30*12` for `360` pay periods.  Or possibly `Math.pow(30,1+montlyRate)` where `monthlyRate = (AR/100)/12` and `AR = annual rate`).

```java
    int a =(1+t)^f;
```

The operator `^` is not power but an `exclusive OR`. You probably didn't want that either.

I recommend you check out this Wiki entry on computing [Mortage Payments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator)

Here is one way to do calculate it and then display it per month.

```java
      double in = 5.5; // annual percentage rate
      double mo_rate = (in / 100) / 12.; // monthly rate
      double PV = 400_000.; // present value (cost of the house).
      double f = Math.pow(1 + mo_rate, 360); // factor resulting from the linear
                                             // expansion

      double payment = mo_rate * PV * f / (f - 1); // Monthly payment including
                                                   // interest and
                                                   // principal

      System.out.printf("Monthly payment is %7.2f%n", payment);
```

Note:  different banks and/or countries may do it differently.

Comment: i have seen your code but i have not started using iteration can you help me fix that without it?

Comment: @Amaka_k  The edited answer simply prints out the monthly payment.  The iteration was just to print the amortization table and was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4,704%"`

---

1. `percent.format(3.92*12)` returns the `String` : `4 704 %` and this can't be parsed to double, because of the space and the % symbol, you just need to multiply it by `100` to consider it as a percentage

   ```
   double r = 3.92 * 12 * 100;
   ```
2. As you're using only `ints` you fall into the [`int division problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0) and you'll get a `0` at the end, so you may use at leat one `double` ot cast one durint the division

   ```
   int a = (1 + t) ^ f;
   double b = (a - 1);
   double c = (t * a) / b;
   double m = p * c;
   // OR
   int a = (1 + t) ^ f;
   int b = (a - 1);
   double c = (t * a) / (double) b;
   double m = p * c;
   ```
3. Also `^` is thr XOR symbol, to use power computation :

   ```
   double a = Math.pow(1+t, f);
   ```

For the result, it depends on `r`:

- `double r = 3.92 * 12 * 100;` gives `-10 308,38 €`
- `double r = 3.92 * 12;` gives `999 998,95 €`

---

And use names that explain what the variable is, as much as possible

Comment: Let me try this because i just got 0 as my answer

Comment: @Amaka_k  any news ? ;)

Comment: Yes, I used double just like you said and got a negative result, thanks you were really helpful to me

Comment: Not certain how ^ is used here in the calculations.  That is an exclusive OR operator.

Comment: @Amaka_k to use power computation : `Math.pow(1+t, f)`

Comment: i was trying to get the power of but was really tough, i will try this as well